# iOS ble write not change value

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Sending data through the iOS (writeValue: forCharacteristic: type :) method works fine without error, but the value does not change. Do you know why?

```
> 2017-06-27 14:53:54.846963+0900 BluetoothSample[12662:5477661] Did
> write  characteristic <CBCharacteristic: 0x1700ad500, UUID =
> 2A588021-4FB2-40F5- 8204-85315DEF11C5, properties = 0xA, value =
> <1357>, notifying = NO>


uint8_t val = 123;
NSData * valData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)&val length:sizeof(val)];


 [self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue:valData forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];


- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {

    if (error) {
         NSLog(@"didWriteValueForCharacteristic With error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        self.receivePaketDataTextView.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[error localizedDescription]];
        return ;
    }

    self.receivePaketDataTextView.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",characteristic.value];
}
```

When I try to write, only the same logs are printed.

Comment: Which value doesn't change?  The value in your peripheral?  What is your peripheral?

Comment: I try to change the characteristic value of ble to 123, but it does not change.

Comment: I understand that, but *where* do you not see the change?  On your peripheral?  What is your peripheral?  Another iOS device?  Some other device?  How do you read the value? Do you get a call to your `didWriteValueFor` `CBPeripheralDelegate` method?  Do you get an error in that method?

Comment: The value of the other device (not iOS Device) does not change. ReadValueForCharacteristic works fine. The writeValue works as well and returns the return value, but not the value.

Comment: On your iOS central  the value of the characteristic in `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` does not reflect the change you just wrote.  You need to issue an explicit read to get the new value.  This is by design

Comment: Thank you. I've got writeValue and readValue that changed the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your iOS central the `value` of the characteristic in `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` does not reflect the change you just wrote.

You need to issue an explicit read to get the new value.

This is by design, since there is no guarantee that the value you have just written is the *current value* of the characteristic; only the peripheral can give you the current value.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
[self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue: valData
           forCharacteristic:self.usedCharacteristic
                        type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
```

Use type: CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse

Also check if you have set the notifier

```
  [self.discoveredPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:self.usedCharacteristic];
```

Before hand in your delegates.

Comment: CBCharacteristicWriteoutResponse should not be inserted. The setNotifyValue method is also executed, but the value of chracteristic does not change to YES.